# Angular .emit no funciona

Tags: html, angular, typescript

He tratado de todo, y no me funciona el EventEmitter de Angular.

Practicamente lo que quiero hacer es emitir un dummy (emit de prueba) para un proyecto que tengo de la escuela. El problema, es que el .emit simplemente no hace nada. Ya revice el parent Component, y ya revide que el metodo que contiene el .emit si funcione (y si funciona, ya que corre console.logs y alerts), pero por alguna razon mi parent component no recibe el evento, y no se que hacer para que reciba el evento. No se si tenga que cambiar alguna configuracion en angular. Ya intente correr el codigo en linux y en windows y es lo mismo.

Typescript del hijo:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Output } from '@angular/core'
import { Contact } from '../contacts.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts-list',
  templateUrl: './contacts-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts-list.component.css']
})
export class ContactsListComponent implements OnInit {
  contacts: Contact[] = [new Contact(1, "R.Kent Jackson", "jacksonk@BYU.edu",2084963771,"../../assets/images/jacksonk.jpg"),
  new Contact(2,"Rex Barzee", "barzeer@byui.edu", 2084963768, "../../assets/images/barzeer.jpg")]

  // // samplecontact: Contact = new Contact(1, "R.Kent Jackson", "jacksonk@BYU.edu",2084963771,"../../assets/images/jacksonk.jpg")

  @Output() selectedContactEvent:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<Contact>();

  @Output("dummy") dummyEmitter:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() {
    
   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onNewContact(){ 
  }
  dummyEmit(){
    this.dummyEmitter.emit("Dummy send");
    console.log("function worked");
  }
  onSelected(contact: Contact) {
    alert("onSelected");
    this.selectedContactEvent.emit(contact);
  }


}
```

HTML hijo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button (click)="dummyEmit()" class="btn btn-success">New Contact </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <app-contact-item *ngFor="let contactItem of contacts"
        [contact]="contactItem"
        (click)="onSelected(contactItem)"
        >
        </app-contact-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript padre:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact } from './contacts.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css']
})
 export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  // //  samplecontact: Contact = new Contact(1, "R.Kent Jackson", "jacksonk@BYU.edu",2084963771,"../../assets/images/jacksonk.jpg")
  selectedContact!: Contact;
   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit(): void {
   }
  // //  alertLog(param){
  // //    alert(param);
  // //  }
  receiveEvent(){
    console.log("Event received");
    alert("Event received");
    this.selectedContact;
  }
 }
```

HTML padre:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <app-contacts-list
        (dummy)="receiveEvent()">
        </app-contacts-list>
        <!-- <p (click)="alertLog(selectedContact)">Hello</p> -->      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <!--// <app-contact-detail *ngIf="selectedContact != undefined || selectedContact != null; else infoText;" [contact]="selectedContact">
        </app-contact-detail> -->
        <app-contact-detail [contact]="selectedContact" *ngIf="selectedContact">
        </app-contact-detail>

        <!-- <ng-template #infoText>
            <p>Please select a recipe</p>
        </ng-template> -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Si corre el console.log de "dummyEmit" que dice "function worked" pero no recibe el evento el padre por alguna razon

Answer (score 1):

En el padre debe tener el nombre dummyEmiter no "dummy"

```
@Output() dummyEmitter:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Padre:

```
<app-contacts-list (dummyEmitter)="receiveEvent()"></app-contacts-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que te quedó corta la implementación, faltan un par de cosas para que funcione como debe de ser, te dejo mis comentarios

Emitimos el contacto cuando se seleccione
**TS hijo**

```
onSelected(contact: Contact) {
  alert("onSelected");
  this.selectedContactEvent.emit(contact);
}
```

Bindeamos el nombre del `emmiter` al `html` y pasamos la información recibida a través de la palabra reservada `$event`

**HTML padre**

```
<app-contact-detail 
  *ngIf="selectedContact"
  [contact]="selectedContact"
  (selectedContactEvent)="receiveEvent($event)"
>
</app-contact-detail>
```

La función debe recibir un contacto, así que ponemos un parámetro de llegada

**TS padre**

```
  receiveEvent( contact: Contact ){
    console.log("Event received");
    console.log(contact);
    this.selectedContact;
  }
```